# Avoid changing ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Q1.Is there a way of avoiding the following behavior in a ggplot?

```
x=c(1,3,4,5,6)
y=c(0.5,2,3,7,1)
n=2
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p <-p + geom_segment(aes(x = x[1], y = y[1], xend = x[2], yend = y[2]), colour = "red")
p <-p + geom_segment(aes(x = x[2], y = y[2], xend = x[3], yend = y[3]), colour = "red")
p
```

[image]

```
x[1]=10
p
```

[image]

The drawing on the plot remains anchored to the value of the numeric values given in input. Do I have to create other variables for storing the coordinates?

Q2.How to draw a [polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) in ggplot?

```
n=length(x)-1
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
for (i in 1:n){
  p <-p + geom_segment(aes(x = x[i], y = y[i], xend = x[i+1], yend = y[i+1]), colour = "red")
  p$plot_env <- list2env(list(x=x,y=y))
  }
```

Answer here: [Drawing polygonal chains in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578530/drawing-polygonal-chains-in-ggplot)

Comment: OK, I take it back, I think your edit should actually be a new question. (There are several answers, either using shifted coordinates `x[-1], x[-length(x)] , ...` but probably better `geom_path()`.)

Comment: @Ben Bolker Can you plot more than one polygonal chain using geom_path()?

Comment: Yes, I think so (use the `group` aesthetic)

Comment: @Ben Bolker geom_path() connects the data from mtcars, not from x and y

Comment: Rather than this back-and-forth in the comments, I really think it would be best if you asked a new question that lays out clearly what you want (hint: you can use the `data=` argument to override the data values for a geom) ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578530/drawing-polygonal-chains-in-ggplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a hack but apparently works: before modifying `x`, do

```
p$plot_env <- list2env(list(x=x,y=y))
```

Then

```
x[1] <- 10
p
```

leaves the plot unchanged.

Comment: Do you think this can be adapted to work with x[i] in a for cycle?

Comment: Don't quite know what you mean.  Edit your question?  (You can modify the variables in the environment via `assign()` ...)

Comment: Please look at Q2.