# Drawing polygonal chains in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to draw multiples [polygonal chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain) in ggplot? I was writing something like:

```
x=c(1,3,4,5,6)
y=c(0.5,2,3,7,1)
z=c(8,2,6,7,8)
n=length(x)-1
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
for (i in 1:n){
  p <-p + geom_segment(aes(x = x[i], y = y[i], xend = x[i+1], yend = y[i+1]), colour = "red")
  p$plot_env <- list2env(list(x=x,y=y))
  }
```

Drawing two polygonal chains:

```
n=length(x)
pol1=c(x,y)
pol2=c(y,z)
g=c(rep(1,n),rep(2,n))
library(ggplot2)
p0 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg))
p0 + geom_path(aes(pol1,pol2,group=g),data=data.frame(pol1,pol2))
```

[image: ggplot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you want here.

- Are you specifying more than one path? I only see a single set of `x` and `y` values.
- What is `z` supposed to be doing?

You can draw a single (unclosed) path via

```
p0 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg))
p <- p0 + geom_path(aes(x,y),data=data.frame(x,y))
```

Or a closed path via

```
p0 + geom_polygon(aes(x,y),data=data.frame(x,y),fill=NA,
             colour="black")
```

If you do have more than one path, you can combine all the vertices in two long vectors `x` and `y`, make up a `g` vector to distinguish paths, and use `aes(x,y,group=g)` to get the paths/polygons drawn separately.

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're trying to do.  If you think my answer will be sufficiently clear and useful to future readers, you could accept it. Otherwise you're welcome to post a more fully-worked-out answer yourself.

Comment: I've accepted it since it is correct, if you think something is unclear, feel free to edit this post.